# Overlaying of element over :before

Tags: css, frontend

I am trying to make a div that will have like a translucent background while being visible like a pop up box. I am a beginner at css. Here is my code and current output:

```
.test {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 53em;
  height: 27em;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 1em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}
.test:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  width: 55em;
  height: 30em;
  display: block;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

The executable code link: [Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a296zr3v/)

I searched up the web but only got z-index. I tried to use that but it still not works.

Thank you!

Comment: where is your HTML? always post a full and executable code in a snippet to help us see the issue and easily edit it for you.

Comment: I have added a js fiddle link to the edit.